# Is there a way to pass environment variable to a Visual Studio project and use it in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight, windows-phone-7, msbuild

I would like my Windows Phone application to access an environment variable of the build machine.

In my scenario I specifically want to pass the USERNAME variable, so when I am looking at phone application's analytics reports in case of debug builds - I can see which developer was running the application and see whether it was me or someone else. I could think of other similar scenarios where it would be useful to have a build-time value accessed at runtime, so I would like to find a generic solution to the problem.

I can think of one solution - use a pre-build event definition to create or update a .cs file with a constant set to the build-time environment variable value, but it seems a bit ugly and I am expecting to see problems with version control systems. I was hoping maybe there was some trick to use DefineConstants or otherwise set it using some simple msbuild project customization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do as you suggested: creating a `.cs` file with a constant during build time. To circumvent potential issues with version control systems, don't add this file to version control and create it in a location ignored by version control (like `obj\Debug` or `obj\Release` folders).

In MSBuild it could look like the following:

Add the following after the final "Import"-Element in your CSPROJ file.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Make sure our file is build on every compile -->
    <CompileDependsOn>
      _CreateMyFile;
      $(CompileDependsOn)
    </CompileDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="_CreateMyFile">

   <!-- Add code to create the file on demand. 
   You could write a custom task, or execute some external tool.

   As an example assume it is created as "$(IntermediateOutputPath)\EnvVars.cs".
   Where IntermediateOutputPath expands to "obj\Debug" or "obj\Release", respectively.
   Either typically beign ignored by version control systems.
   -->

   <!-- Add file to files to be compiled. -->
   <ItemGroup>
       <Compile Include="$(IntermediateOutputPath)\EnvVars.cs"/>
   </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

You might consider putting the above in a custom `.proj` file, which you import into your CSPROJ files.

Oh, and I don't find that ugly at all. Personally, I use it for all kinds of such tasks, like assembly version attributes, etc.

**Update:**
To prevent the target from being called on every build (or F5, etc.) you can use the `Inputs` and `Outputs` attributes of the [`Target` element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t50z2hka%28v=VS.90%29.aspx). The MSDN page is not too helpfull, but basically it works as follows: MSBuild will check if all files specified in the `Output` attribute are up-to-date with respect to the files specified in the `Inputs` attribute.

You could thus change the target definition like so (PropertyGroup element remains the same and only added for completeness):

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Make sure our file is build on every compile -->
    <CompileDependsOn>
      _CreateMyFile;
      $(CompileDependsOn)
    </CompileDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="_CreateMyFile"
   Inputs="$(IntermediateOutputPath)\EnvVars.cs"
   Outputs="$(IntermediateOutputPath)\EnvVars.cs">

   <!-- Create EnvVars.cs file -->
   <WriteLinesToFile
        File="$(IntermediateOutputPath)\EnvVars.cs"
        Lines="namespace Foo {}"
        Overwrite="true"
        Encoding="Unicode"/>

   <!-- Add file to files to be compiled. -->
   <ItemGroup>
      <Compile Include="$(IntermediateOutputPath)\EnvVars.cs"/>
   </ItemGroup>

   <!-- Add file to files to be removed on target "clean". -->
   <ItemGroup>
      <FileWrites Include="$(IntermediateOutputPath)\EnvVars.cs"/>
   </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

The trick here is the following: if EnvVars.cs does not exist it will be created. If it does exist (then) it will no longer be created, thus not forcing a build on F5. However, we have to provide some way of getting rid of the file. Hence adding it to the `FileWrites` ItemGroup, which contains the files to be removed when the "clean" or "rebuild" targets (or the respective menu commands in Visual Studio) will be called. So if you want a new EnvVars.cs file, just do a rebuild or clean.

Comment: Won't that make my project rebuild every time I hit F5?

Answer (score 3):

You can try the mobile application block, which is basically just an app config for mobile.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/07/06/app-config-for-wp7-applications.aspx

And this seems like a tidy way to set msbuild up to select an appropriate app config file.

http://www.timvw.be/2008/03/17/easily-switching-between-appconfig-files-with-msbuild/

Combine these two methods and you could have your build set the configuration and the application use the config file.

Comment: I presume this would allow me to select from a predetermined list of app.config files depending on the active solution configuration, but does not allow for passing any random environment variable, so I would need to have a separate app.config file for each user, have a solution configuration for each user and keep these up to date. I am looking for something that will just work for anyone doing Debug builds.